# How to serve different config settings in flask app to uwsgi using create_app?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

In my Flask application's `config.py` i have `LocalConfig` and `ProdConfig` and latter is to be used in production, once app is deployed.

Now i'm using `uWsgi` to serve app to `Nginx` and here the `myapp.wsgi` i have created.

```
from myapp import create_app
from myapp.config import ProdConfig

app = create_app(config=ProdConfig)
```

and in one of other `app.py` `create_app` is defined as:

```
def create_app(config=None, app_name=None, blueprints=None):

    # some code
    app = Flask(app_name, instance_path=INSTANCE_FOLDER_PATH, instance_relative_config=True)
    configure_app(app, config)
    # some other code

    return app

def configure_app(app, config=None):
    """Different ways of configurations."""

    app.config.from_object(LocalConfig)
    app.config.from_pyfile('production.cfg', silent=True)

    if config:
        app.config.from_object(config)
```

I want to know, will it properly with `uWSGI`? Will uWSGI be able to applying the `ProdConfig` successfully?

Or is it better to use Environment Variables to distinguish between different config settings? Like `if os.environ.get('PROD', True): #do something`?

Which way is better? Flask's `create_app()` one or the env variable one? Any other suitable approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way of doing this is storing the configurations in a dictionary.

```
class Config:
     ALL_CAPS_CONFIG = 'SOME VALUE'

class DevConfig(Config):
    pass

class TestConfig(Config):
    pass

class ProdConfig(Config):
    pass

configs = {
  'dev'  : DevConfig,
  'test' : TestConfig,
  'prod' : ProdConfig,
  'default' : ProdConfig
  }
```

And then where you actually create your app, you'd do something like this::

```
from config import configs
import os

evn = os.environ.get('MY_FLASK_APP_ENV', 'default')

create_app(config=configs[evn])
```

That way you can easily switch between the environments by changing a variable in your shell.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually much nicer to point an environment variable to a completely separate config.py file. Personally I have a config.py file that contains my base and development settings, then another config.py for my production configuration, the location of which is specified from an environment variable.

I would recommend that you look at the [Flask Configuration](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#development-production) documentation, as it does a good job at explaining how the configuration files should be setup.