# Using flask.request.is_secure inside create_app()

Tags: python, flask, request

The desire is to configure a Flask app differently based on whether it is running on HTTP or HTTPS.

The following code will raise a RuntimeError.

How do I dynamically configure Flask?

It is a bit of a pain to go in and manually change the different settings every time I deploy.  Automatic solution preferred. It seems strange that Flask has no mechanism for knowing which machine it is running on until after it is running.  Maybe flask.request is the wrong way.

I read [this documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#development-production) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745390/how-to-serve-different-config-settings-in-flask-app-to-uwsgi-using-create-app).

```
from flask import Flask, request


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['DEBUG'] = not request.is_secure       
    return app


# Initialize App
app = create_app()
```

Error details.

> RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
>
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that
>   needed an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing
>   for information about how to avoid this problem.

Another try based on the [flask config docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#development-production).  Received the same RuntimeError.

```
# Configuration Options
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    FLASKS3_BUCKET_NAME = 'nueverest'
    FLASKS3_USE_HTTPS = True
    USE_S3_DEBUG = False


class Production(Config):
    pass


class Development(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    USE_S3_DEBUG = True


app = Flask(__name__)         # Initialize Application

if request.is_secure:               # Select Configuration
    app.config.from_object(Production)
else:
    app.config.from_object(Development)
```

Comment: How can you expect to access a request object before there have been any requests?

Comment: Makes sense.  I didn't fully understand how the request object worked.

Comment: @PJSantoro that link was already provided in the question.

Comment: Down voters explain why you are downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel Roseman explained, `flask.request` cannot be used since a request must occur first (chicken and egg).

> Solution: Use `uuid.getnode()` to uniquely identify which machine the
>   code is running on.

For this to be scalable each developer must create their own secrets.py file. The file should not be added to VCS as it is unique to each developer. It looks like this.

```
import uuid


def is_production():
    """ Determines if app is running on the production server via uuid comparison.

    HOW TO USE:
    Open a terminal
    > python
    > import uuid
    > uuid.getnode()
    12345678987654321  <-- Copy whatever is returned and replace 111111111 with this.

    Compare uuid for the machine against the known uuid(s) of your development machine(s).
    :return: (bool) True if code is running on the production server, and False otherwise.
    """
    developer_machines = [111111111, ]
    return uuid.getnode() not in developer_machines
```

app.py imports secrets.is_production() and looks like this.

```
from flask import Flask
from secrets import is_production


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['DEBUG'] = not is_production()
    return app


# Initialize App
app = create_app()
```

> Scalability: Each developer manages their own secrets.py file. This is
>   scalable to any number of developers, and does not require the use of
>   Environment Variables which can complicate testing, development, and
>   deployment.